# How to use HTTP2 request multiplexing in Android

Tags: android, okhttp, http2

From my Android app, I am trying to communicate with an image webserver, which supports HTTP2 multiplexing.

This webserver can send me some 300 images over a single TCP connection (multiplexing).

After many tries, I ended up using OkHttp, since it supports HTTP2, but it looks like OkHttp is not using multiplexing at all, and is sending all these 300+ images in separate responses.

What is the working way to use HTTP2 multiplexing on Android?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check gRPC that provides `multiplexing` over `HTTP2` and it has library for Android!

Comment: Just checked. Still having doubts whether grpc can be used in a production app, since a grpc server can't run in an Android device, needs my localhost to communicate with the app. Would you have any sample code somewhere?

Comment: Looks like I'll need this webserver to run a grpc server, in order to get grpc working on my app. Is that correct?

Comment: You don't need to run server on Android! You just implement gRPC client on Android same Retrofit and so on.

Comment: Does the webserver that is serving these images on http2, need to run grpc server? or does it need to support RPC in general?

Comment: Yes, you need run gRPC server on your server!

Comment: That's the thing. I don't have access to the webserver